# Solving the system $2y^2-5x+13=0$ and $x+4y=-1$

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Let's say you have two simultaneous equations:

$$2y^2-5x+13=0$$ $$x+4y=-1$$

How do I proceed?

Should I multiply it by $x$ or $y$? Or both?

Comment: Use that $x=-1-4y$ in the first equation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: General strategy: try to solve one of the equations for one of the variables, in this case $x$ in terms of $y$. Then substitute the solved-for variable into the other equation, to get a single equation in the other variable, and this should be handleable.

Comment: Thank you @Lubin!

Answer (score 0):

I would $$y=\frac{1}{4}(-x-1)$$ plug in to the first equation:
$$2\left(\frac{1}{4}(-x-1)\right)^2-5x+13=0$$
At first simplify 442\left(\frac{1}4}(-x-1)\right)^2=$$\frac{1}{8}(x^2+2x+1)$$ the we multiply the whole equation by $8$
$$x^2+2x+1-40x+104=0$$
combining like terms

$$x^2-38x+105=0$$
and by the quadratic Formula we get
$$x_{1,2}=19\pm\sqrt{361-105}$$

Comment: Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Can you solve the quadratic one?

Comment: Not yet but I'll probably get there once I understand the entire formula

Comment: Can I ask you a question here?

Comment: Ok i will solve it for you!

Comment: Yes you can,but i don't know all the answers!

Comment: Huh? Wait, you want to solve the quadratic one for me?

Comment: It's fine I just need to know what to do

Comment: Ok I have a two functions $f(x)$ and $h(x)$

Comment: We need to find $x$ in a way $hf(x)$ equals to $4x$

Comment: I got that $hf(x)$ is $4x^2+4x-2$

Comment: But how do I find $x$?

Comment: It is much easier (i.e. less messy) to solve for $x$ in the second equation and substitute into the first equation (as explained in mfl's tip) than do it this way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating $x$,

$$2y^2-5(-4y-1)+13=2y^2+20y+18=0$$

and by the quadratic formula,

$$y=-9\text{ or }y=-1.$$  $x$ follows.

Comment: Thank you for that!